# Retrieving and parsing data from mywebsearch (search engine)

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have been trying to make a tool that allows me to enter a keyword and have it automatically do this:

```
int.search.mywebsearch.com/mywebsearch/GGweb.jhtml?searchfor=Keyword
```

Then, scrape all the URLs on the page.

However, when I go to regexxr or regex101, it seems like the urls are not there and I can't use regular expression to get it. How can I scrape something that can't be downloaded using `WebClient.downloadstring(url)`?

Code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
foreach(string s in Keywords)
{
    string url = wc.DownloadString("https://int.search.mywebsearch.com/mywebsearch/GGmain.jhtml?&searchfor=" + s);
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(url, @""); // Didn't write any regex yet
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you can't figure out a regular expression for getting URLs from HTML?

Comment: I can, for other search engine everything works fine, I don't know why it doesn't work for this engine

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're saying is not working. Your question shows you downloading search results. Are you saying that the download isn't working or that you are downloading and you can't find URLs? And if these aren't working, what's the expected vs actual behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex:

```
<a[^>]+href\s?=\s?"([^"]+)"[^>]?>
```

Working [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/Qtal8b/1)